# Twitter Bootstrap: hiding a row-fluid container without the row's other containers to the right sliding left?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a page with some dynamic content. The main layout is in 3 containers within the same fluid row. I want the first container either to display one of two types of lists, or be absent -- varying by the state of the page.
However when I try to remove the element with a jquery function like `$("#container-id").hide()`, it slides the containers to the right of it left, skewing the layout of the page. Is there a way to remove this container from view without the other containers shifting left?

Here is an example of what is happening:
http://jsfiddle.net/PHaeA/27/

And here is an example of how I want the containers to appear when the first one is absent: http://jsfiddle.net/gLTyF/5/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the easiest workaround would be to (if possible) add a div inside the span with the content and hide *that* instead of the whole column.

Another way might be to override the twitter bootstrap style to make it float right instead of left:

```
 .row-fluid [class*="span"] {
     float: right; }
```

but I'd guess that would be more likely to cause unintended consequences.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the space preserved, you can use

```
$('#col1').css({visibility:"hidden"});
```